# Как из БД на postgresql вывести группированные значения

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы spr_detail_options (названия всех опций) и detail_options (значения всех опций). Они связаны между собой.
spr_detail_options столбцы:

```
id | name | icon
```

detail_options столбцы:

```
id | spr_detail_option_id | name | parent_id | icon
```

Связь через fk fk_spr_detail_optionl_option к spr_detail_option_id.
Подскажите как вывести данные из этих 2х таблиц, чтобы в итоге получить, что то подобное

```
spr.name | [{d.id, d.name}, {d.id, d.name}, {d.id, d.name}]
```

Т.е. таблицу где первый столбец это название опции, а второй массив объектов или хотя бы просто массив всех значений опции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  spr.name,
  array_agg(d.name)
from spr_detail_options as spr
inner join detail_options as d
  on d.spr_detail_option_id = spr.id
group by spr.name;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.